# Is there a minimum hardware requirement for SKLearn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-selection, sklearn-pandas

this is not a programming question per se, in the sense that my code is fine, but more a question about the speed my code runs at.

I am trying to do some feature selection using SKLearn. My actual dataframe is about 20,000 rows, with 30 features. The problem I have is I can't get my program to finish running once it's at the feature selectin stage, it just runs and runs for hours on end without completing.

So I decided to just use a quick example from the SKLearn website:

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
>>> from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVR
>>> X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)
>>> estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
>>> selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5)
>>> selector = selector.fit(X, y)
>>> selector.support_ 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False])
>>> selector.ranking_
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2, 5])
```

This runs fine, and maybe takes a few seconds. If I stick the `n_samples` up to 2,000 again it runs fine, but takes a bit longer. I tried 20,000 `n_samples`, but stopped the process after a while as it was taking too long.

So I then decided to cut my `df` down to size, and gave it just 1,000 rows, with 10 features. Using exactly the same code from the SKLearn website, but substituting X for `df.drop('label', axis=1)`, and y for `df['label']`, it's been running for over an hour now with no end in site.

Given I was able to get the example code to run fine with 2,000 `n_samples`, I am mystified as to why I can't get the same feature selection process to work on my own data.

Is there a minimum hardware requirement for this process? I have tried on a 2011 Mac with 4gb RAM, and a 2015 Windows machine with 6gb RAM and neither works.

My data consists of stock prices, with Technical Analysis Indicators from a library simply called `ta`. It's in the form of a Pandas DataFrame, I don't know if this makes a difference given that the example code from SKLearn isn't a Pandas `df`?

Any clues/help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occurs with `RFECV`:

How does it work?

> We initially start with all the features. For every step or iteration
>   the worst x number of features (i.e the features which have the lowest
>   absolute value in case of linear models) are eliminated using the
>   "step" parameter till "n_features" are left.
>
> The RFECV object helps to tune or find this n_features parameter using
>   cross-validation. F**or every step where "step" number of features are
>   eliminated, it calculates the score on the validation data**. The
>   number of features left at the step which gives the maximum score on
>   the validation data, is considered to be "the best n_features" of your
>   data.
>   [Reference](https://www.quora.com/scikit-learn-How-does-RFECV-make-use-of-cross-validation)

So  you can play with the step parameter. right now It is eliminating one feature and calculates the score again.

Normally there is no minimum set-up for it,

what could also be the case, that you have an error in your original file, this takes quite long to load sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I played around with the step, I even put the step to 5 with the minimum number of features set to 5 as well, which in my mind suggests it only needs to drop 5 and stop after the first round, but again it just runs and runs.